# Set value of radio button based on user selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on a users selections of the three dropdowns, I want to set the value of a given radio button from the objects below.

For example, if I chose "Dropdown 1-1" from the first select tag and left the other two blank, radio_button_4 would now have a value of "r(5000-R)".

If I chose "Dropdown 1-1" and "Dropdown 2-2" and left the third blank, the value for radio_button_4 would read "r(10000-R)".

I've tried different variations of nested loops but can't seem to figure out the correct order to get my desired result.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var objs = [{
      selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
      selected_option_value_2: "",
      selected_option_value_3: "",
      output: "5000-R",
      name_1: "ABC_1",
      name_2: "",
      name_3: "",
      radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
    }, {
      selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
      selected_option_value_2: "2-2",
      selected_option_value_3: "",
      output: "10000-R",
      name_1: "ABC_1",
      name_2: "MNO_2",
      name_3: "",
      radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
    }, {
      selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
      selected_option_value_2: "2-2",
      selected_option_value_3: "3-3",
      output: "15000-R",
      name_1: "ABC_1",
      name_2: "MNO_2",
      name_3: "YZ_3",
      radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
    }];

       $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        $("#wrapper").find("input[type='radio']").each(function(i, o) {
          var btn_name = $(this).attr("name");
          $.each(objs, function(index, rule) {
            if (btn_name == rule.radio_btn_name) {
              console.log(rule);
            }
          });
        });
       });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div>
         <select class="group_1">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1-1" name="ABC_1">Dropdown 1-1</option>
          <option value="1-2" name="DEF_2">Dropdown 1-2</option>
          <option value="1-3" name="GHI_3">Dropdown 1-3</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      <br>
      <div>
       <input type="radio" name="radio_button_1" value="r()">
       <input type="radio" name="radio_button_2" value="o()">
       <input type="radio" name="radio_button_3" value="n()">
      </div>
      <div>
       <select class="group_1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="2-1" name="JKL_1">Dropdown 2-1</option>
        <option value="2-2" name="MNO_2">Dropdown 2-2</option>
        <option value="2-3" name="PQR_3">Dropdown 2-3</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_button_4" value="r()">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_button_5" value="o()">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_button_6" value="n()">
      </div>
      <div>
        <select class="group_1">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="3-1" name="STU_1">Dropdown 3-1</option>
          <option value="3-2" name="VWX_2">Dropdown 3-2</option>
          <option value="3-3" name="YZ_3">Dropdown 3-3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_button_7" value="r()">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_button_8" value="o()">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_button_9" value="n()">
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmd1603/bvxdbse9/9/)

Comment: Do you want the name to change to something different if multiple radio buttons from the same line are selected, rather than just one?

Comment: @freginold no the name will still be "radio_button_4". The only thing that will change will be its value depending on which options are selected. I should add that "name_1" corresponds with "selected_option_value_1" and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

davila!
As I understand your problem - you want to dynamically assign your radio button a value based of dropdown selection and your `objs` rules.

You seem very close to the solution. I hope the below code will help to understand what you are missing.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
     <select class="group_1" id="select_1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1-1" name="ABC_1">Dropdown 1-1</option>
      <option value="1-2" name="DEF_2">Dropdown 1-2</option>
      <option value="1-3" name="GHI_3">Dropdown 1-3</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <input type="radio" name="radio_button_1" value="r()">
   <input type="radio" name="radio_button_2" value="o()">
   <input type="radio" name="radio_button_3" value="n()">
  </div>
  <div>
   <select class="group_1" id="select_2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="2-1" name="JKL_1">Dropdown 2-1</option>
    <option value="2-2" name="MNO_2">Dropdown 2-2</option>
    <option value="2-3" name="PQR_3">Dropdown 2-3</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_4" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_5" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_6" value="n()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="group_1" id="select_3">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="3-1" name="STU_1">Dropdown 3-1</option>
      <option value="3-2" name="VWX_2">Dropdown 3-2</option>
      <option value="3-3" name="YZ_3">Dropdown 3-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_7" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_8" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_9" value="n()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

    var objs = [{
      selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
      selected_option_value_2: "",
      selected_option_value_3: "",
      output: "5000-R",
      name_1: "ABC_1",
      name_2: "",
      name_3: "",
      radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
    }, {
      selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
      selected_option_value_2: "2-2",
      selected_option_value_3: "",
      output: "10000-R",
      name_1: "ABC_1",
      name_2: "MNO_2",
      name_3: "",
      radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
    }, {
      selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
      selected_option_value_2: "2-2",
      selected_option_value_3: "3-3",
      output: "15000-R",
      name_1: "ABC_1",
      name_2: "MNO_2",
      name_3: "YZ_3",
      radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
    }];

       $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        $("#wrapper").find("input[type='radio']").each(function(i, o) {
          var btn = $(this);
          var btn_name = $(this).attr("name");
          $.each(objs, function(index, rule) {
            if (btn_name == rule.radio_btn_name) {
              if(rule.selected_option_value_1 == $('#select_1').val()
                  && rule.selected_option_value_2 == $('#select_2').val()
                  && rule.selected_option_value_3 == $('#select_3').val()) {
                btn.val(rule.output);
                console.log(rule.output);
              }
            }
          });
        });
       });
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this solution working for you? It doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: When I select "Dropdown 1-1" and click "submit" I can see 5000-R assigned to "radio_button_4" and printed in console too.
>> For "Dropdown 1-1" + "Dropdown 2-2", the value is 10000-R.
>> For "Dropdown 1-1" + "Dropdown 2-2" + "Dropdown 3-3", the value is 15000-R.    

Are you expecting something else?

Comment: Jk you are correct! Thanks! I am selecting this as the correct answer based on my question! Can you tell me how I would also apply this when the amount of select dropdowns is more than 3 or unknown?

Comment: Thanks!
I would suggest using array for `rule.selected_option_value_#` and then loop through comparing the `rule.selected_option_value[i]` with `$('#select_'+i).val()`.
To get a combined result of all comparisons, you can have a boolean `var match=true` and then keep ANDing the result of all comparisons.
`match = match && (rule.selected_option_value[i]==$('#select_'+i).val())` in the loop.
After the loop, if `match == true`, you can use the value to assign to the radio button.

Comment: can you take a look at my JS and tell me where I'm off using your suggestion above? thanks https://jsfiddle.net/cmd1603/bvxdbse9/17/

Comment: @ChrisDavila I have updated your JSFiddle. Check this one - https://jsfiddle.net/bvxdbse9/23/

Comment: I just realized my maximum amount of "selected_option_value" will be 3 so the latest revision won't work if I delete the "4" name and empty string from the objects. I need to compare at most 3 values to an unknown number of select dropdowns. I now remember this was the original roadblock I had from the beginning. Any advice?

Comment: I am confused with above scenario. How do you want to compare 3 config values with n number of dropdown values?
Suppose you have 5 dropdowns, how do you want to compare these against the rules `selected_option_value_1`, `selected_option_value_2` and `selected_option_value_3`

Comment: Your last question is a perfect scenario for my problem. I would then need to somehow loop through all 5 dropdowns, checking for a matching "rule combination" from the objects with  `selected_option_value_1` , `selected_option_value_2`, `selected_option_value_3`. If one of those "rule combination" exists, then give that radio button the "output" value how you did previously. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, @ChrisDavila

Comment: Given the new parameters, I've created a new question. I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865043/assign-value-of-radio-button-based-on-dynamic-number-of-user-selected-values

Answer (score 1):

1) I add group to your objs;

2) Changed the class group in select's;

3) i changed your js to call function every time some select is changed;

4) create function to get new value based ou selected values comparing selected_option_rule.

https://jsfiddle.net/shjgj2s2/5/

```js
var objs = [{
      group: "group_1",
        selected_option_value1: "1-1",
        selected_option_value2: "",
        selected_option_value3: "",
        output: "5000-R",
        name_1: "ABC_1",
        name_2: "",
        name_3: "",
        radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
      }, {
       group: "group_2",
        selected_option_value1: "1-1",
        selected_option_value2: "2-2",
        selected_option_value3: "",
        output: "10000-R",
        name_1: "ABC_1",
        name_2: "MNO_2",
        name_3: "",
        radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
      }, {
       group: "group_3",
        selected_option_value1: "1-1",
        selected_option_value2: "2-2",
        selected_option_value3: "3-3",
        output: "15000-R",
        name_1: "ABC_1",
        name_2: "MNO_2",
        name_3: "YZ_3",
        radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4"
      }];
      
    function ChangeRadio(btn_name, group_class){
       $.each(objs, function(index, rule) {   

            if(rule.selected_option_value1 == $('.group_1').val()
                  && rule.selected_option_value2 == $('.group_2').val()
                  && rule.selected_option_value3 == $('.group_3').val()) {
                $("input[name=" + rule.radio_btn_name +"]").val("r(" + rule.output + ")");
                return false;
              }else{
        $("input[name=radio_button_4]").val("r()");
              }
        });
        console.log($("input[name=radio_button_4]").val());
    }
      
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      $("select").on("change", function(e){
       var btn_name = $("option:selected", this).attr("name");
          var group_class = $(this).attr("class");
          ChangeRadio(btn_name, group_class);
      });

      $("#submit").on("click", function() {
       //somenthing
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <select class="group_1">
      <option value="">Please make a selection</option>
      <option value="1-1" name="ABC_1">Dropdown 1-1</option>
      <option value="1-2" name="DEF_2">Dropdown 1-2</option>
      <option value="1-3" name="GHI_3">Dropdown 1-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_1" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_2" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_3" value="n()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="group_2">
      <option value="">Please make a selection</option>
      <option value="2-1" name="JKL_1">Dropdown 2-1</option>
      <option value="2-2" name="MNO_2">Dropdown 2-2</option>
      <option value="2-3" name="PQR_3">Dropdown 2-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_4" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_5" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_6" value="n()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="group_3">
      <option value="">Please make a selection</option>
      <option value="3-1" name="STU_1">Dropdown 3-1</option>
      <option value="3-2" name="VWX_2">Dropdown 3-2</option>
      <option value="3-3" name="YZ_3">Dropdown 3-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_7" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_8" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_9" value="n()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: On change it is always making the value "15000-R", it needs to check all 3 dropdowns before giving the radio button a value. If the first dropdown selection is "Dropdown 1-1" and the other two are blank, then the  radio value should be "5000-R".

Comment: See now, I hope it helps you get closer to the desired result https://jsfiddle.net/shjgj2s2/3/

Comment: The solution above is still not getting the value if all 3 dropdowns are selected correctly. Also keep in mind I am simply recreating a scenario for my web app, my name/value pairs will be dynamic so hard-coded solutions won't work

Comment: you're right. After seeing Nitesh answer, I was able to understand out your question.