# Assign value of radio button based on dynamic number of user selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a user makes his/her selections of the five select dropdowns, I want to set the value of a radio button from field "radio_btn_name" based on **up to 3** of the users selections. Think of each object as a "rule". If a combination of selections matches that rule, give "radio_btn_x" the "output" value.

In [Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801840/set-value-of-radio-button-based-on-user-selected-options) of my question I achieved my desired result when the number of "selected_option_names_" is equal to the number of select dropdowns. However, I need to be able to check for a dynamic number of dropdowns against only **up to 3** user selections.

I imagine the solution will be drastically different from part 1, as a result I feel a new question is warranted.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmd1603/bvxdbse9/31/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

// A successful solution would render all these rules true, radio_button_4, 
// radio_button_8 and radio_button_1 would get their respective new values
var objs = [{
  selected_option_name_1: "select_1",
  selected_option_name_2: "",
  selected_option_name_3: "",      
  selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
  selected_option_value_2: "",
  selected_option_value_3: "",
  radio_btn_name: "radio_button_4",
  output: "5000-R"
}, {
  selected_option_name_1: "select_1",
  selected_option_name_2: "select_2",
  selected_option_name_3: "select_5",     
  selected_option_value_1: "1-1",
  selected_option_value_2: "2-2",
  selected_option_value_3: "5-2",
  output: "10000-R",
  radio_btn_name: "radio_button_8"
}, {
  selected_option_name_1: "select_4",
  selected_option_name_2: "",
  selected_option_name_3: "",     
  selected_option_value_1: "4-1",
  selected_option_value_2: "",
  selected_option_value_3: "",
  output: "15000-R",
  radio_btn_name: "radio_button_1"
}];
 // Solution for part 1. Will only work if number of dropdowns == "selected_option_name_"
   $("#submit").on("click", function() {
    $("#wrapper").find("input[type='radio']").each(function(i, o) {
      var btn = $(this);
      var btn_name = $(this).attr("name");
      $.each(objs, function(index, rule) {
        if (btn_name == rule.radio_btn_name) {
          if(rule.selected_option_value_1 == $('#select_1').val()
              && rule.selected_option_value_2 == $('#select_2').val()
              && rule.selected_option_value_3 == $('#select_3').val()) {
            btn.val(rule.output);
            console.log(rule.output);
          }
        }
      });
    });
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
     <select class="group_1" name="select_1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1-1">Dropdown 1-1</option>
      <option value="1-2">Dropdown 1-2</option>
      <option value="1-3">Dropdown 1-3</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_1" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_2" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_3" value="n()">
  </div>
  <div>
   <select class="group_1" name="select_2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="2-1">Dropdown 2-1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Dropdown 2-2</option>
    <option value="2-3">Dropdown 2-3</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_4" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_5" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_6" value="n()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select class="group_1" name="select_3">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="3-1">Dropdown 3-1</option>
      <option value="3-2">Dropdown 3-2</option>
      <option value="3-3">Dropdown 3-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_7" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_8" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_9" value="n()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <select class="group_1" name="select_4">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="4-1">Dropdown 4-1</option>
      <option value="4-2">Dropdown 4-2</option>
      <option value="4-3">Dropdown 4-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_10" value="r()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_11" value="o()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_button_12" value="n()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <select class="group_1" name="select_5">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="5-1">Dropdown 5-1</option>
      <option value="5-2">Dropdown 5-2</option>
      <option value="5-3">Dropdown 5-3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you can implement a function and call it on change for select boxes. Inside the function you may add the logic to check the dynamically selected values. Hope it helps.

Comment: @amitmah care to elaborate?

Comment: Hi @chris-davila, Here is an example HTML (select1, select2, select3 ... select5) (radio1,..radio3) . You can put an onchange event (calling a common function) on each of these html control, whenever user changes any of these you can validate your display logic inside the common function. Based on the logic you can change the HTML display as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: When I look at your first rule, it seems that you want value `5000-R` when `1-1` is selected in dropdown `select_1`. Values of other dropdowns don't matter. Is it what you intend to?

Comment: @Nitesh yes that is correct. And same for the last rule, if 4-1 is selected on `select_4` the value of `radio_button_1` will be `15000-R` no matter what else is selected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution wasn't as far off as I thought. I just needed to add an input type hidden with name equal to empty string to account for any empty strings in my objects.

I also updated my jQuery to find the value of names vs id's from part one of my post.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmd1603/bvxdbse9/45/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#submit").on("click", function() {
    $("#wrapper").find("input[type='radio']").each(function(i, o) {
      var btn = $(this);
      var btn_name = $(this).attr("name");
      $.each(objs, function(index, rule) {
        if (btn_name == rule.radio_btn_name) {
          if(rule.selected_option_value_1 == $('[name="'+rule.selected_option_name_1 + '"]').val()
              && rule.selected_option_value_2 == $('[name="'+rule.selected_option_name_2 + '"]').val()
              && rule.selected_option_value_3 == $('[name="'+rule.selected_option_name_3 + '"]').val()) {
            btn.val(rule.output);
            console.log(rule.output);
          }
        }
      });
    });
   });
  });
```

```html
   
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="" value="">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```